# Get field in each post types in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use ACF and Post types.

I have a post types named : exposants

In each post I have two custom fields : link and activity

I would like to publish each exposant with their two custom fields

```
function get_exposant() {
    $post = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'exposants',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'post_title'
    ));

    ?>
    <?php if ($post->have_posts()) : while ( $post->have_posts()) : $post->the_post();
        $exposant_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'exposant_link', true);
        $exposant_activity = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'exposant_activity', true);
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $exposant_link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $exposant_activity; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

The list display the title of each post but I don't get the link and activity, can I have some help to get them please ?

Comment: Have you printed out the content of $exposant_link and $exposant_activity? Are you sure, that the other line is not there? It may be only hidden somehow with CSS.

Comment: @muka.gergely, I have change my code, I updated it. My list display each title but whitout link and activity

Comment: I would try ACF once more - but with explicitly giving the ID to the function, like so: $exposant_link = get_field( 'exposant_link', 79 ); (79 is of course a made up number - change it to an ID that should be correct with your settings). The other thing is I always print_r (or echo) the vars if I know something should work, but it's not - that way I can see whether the information is there, or not. And a last suggestion at this stage: try to name your query variable other than $post. $post is something like a reserved word in WP, and that may mess up your function.